# Installing Ubuntu Phone cant get into bootloader

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Following https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

Model Samsung GT-S7392

Android 4.1.2

*Android > Settings > Developer Options > USB Debugging = checked
Android > Settings > Developer Options > USB Connection = MTP*

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash phablet-tools
$ adb reboot bootloader  // phone reboots to normal screen !
$ fastboot devices
$ sudo fastboot oem unlock
< waiting for device >   // Control+C
```

I've seen some talk of which phones this might work on, but nothing on the web page above.  Should it work on my Samsung?

Answer (score 1):

Samsung GT-S7392 is not supported, please read the instructions you are following, because at the second paragraph are links for supported devices.

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/devices/

Comment: Thanks for that.  The list is so short I didn't think it could be an up to date full list.